# Specific Wordpress page SSL exception through htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

I know this is not the first time someone has asked this, but I tried other solutions and they don't seem to work.

So I have a website with a SSL certificate and a redirect rule in my .htaccess file to point visitors to https. However, there is one specific page I want to exclude from SSL.

This is the code in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So my question is, how do I create a rule that excludes www.example.com/shop from SSL?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you can use another `RewriteCond` on the redirect to block redirecting for that particular URL. However, how are you going to handle the resources loaded by that page? It will load stuff like images, CSS, Javascript, etc. Should those be loaded over plain old HTTP too? And what happens when something clicks on a like to view their shopping cart, will it go to another URL (and thus go over HTTPS again)?

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but it sounds a bit silly to me. Why would you want to exclude only one particular page from a safe & secure connection? (And why wouldn't you serve the whole site over TLS?) But maybe you tell us the reason for this so maybe we can help you find a different solution?

Comment: The shop is embedded in a simple wordpress page through an iframe, but does not support https. (I know it's ancient technology, but there is simply no alternative for this customer) So I need this page to be redirected to http so the embedded shop in the iframe will load.